# DateTime precision issue when filter objects

Tags: office365, office365api, microsoft-graph-api

I'm using a `msgraph-sdk-javascript` version `0.1.2` for a sample application - I'm reading a list of contacts via MS Graph API ordered by modification date using this URL:

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/contacts?$orderby=lastModifiedDateTime asc&$top=10&$filter=lastModifiedDateTime gt 2016-10-24T14:21:03Z`

It works well, however there is one issue - the precision of the `lastModifiedDateTime` property in the output is not the same as is used for query.

In order to implement the proper paging when selecting a long list of contacts I remember the `lastModifiedDateTime` of the last element in the resulting array, so that next time I will select all elements with the `lastModifiedDateTime` *after* the element I saw already. This is however does not work as.

For example if I have an element with `lastModifiedDateTime` value that is returned as `2016-10-24T14:21:03Z` however if I query all elements with `lastModifiedDateTime>2016-10-24T14:21:03Z` I still see the same element as before, which I don't see if I select `lastModifiedDateTime>2016-10-24T14:21:03.999Z`.

Do you know how can I get a millisecond precision `lastModifiedDateTime` as output?

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned this behavior occurs due to a loss in precision, the filter expression:

```
lastModifiedDateTime gt 2016-10-24T14:21:03Z
```

corresponds to the following one (with millisecond part included):

```
lastModifiedDateTime gt 2016-10-24T14:21:03.000Z
```

**About OData DateTime format**

`Contact.LastModifiedDateTime` is internally stored with more precision than a second, see [`DateTimeOffset` structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset(v=vs.110).aspx) for a more details which in turn contains [`DateTimeOffset.Millisecond` Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset.millisecond(v=vs.110).aspx)

Having said that you could consider the following options:

- include millisecond part in `$filter` query option as was
  demonstrated before
- modify filter expression to: `$filter=lastModifiedDateTime ge 2016-10-24T14:21:04Z` This is a similar query to include all the contacts with `lastModifiedDateTime` after `2016-10-24T14:21:03Z`

Comment: Thanks Vadim, my question however is - will I see the milliseconds in API response? Because currently I don't see that so I can include milliseconds in query but I don't know exact milliseconds when checking the values returned by API.